# How to recall the "Create Customer Order" form customized retail form?

Tags: c#, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, dynamics-ax-xpo

I am trying to recall the `Create Customer Order` FORM using the following line of code from my customized form:

```
this.Application.RunOperation(PosisOperations.ConvertCustomerOrder, null);
```

But it is giving me following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Any clue? As i am passing the posTransaction object from blank operation to my customized form and even tried by writing the code like this:

```
this.Application.RunOperation(PosisOperations.ConvertCustomerOrder, posTransaction);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Note: From the "Blank Operation" project same line of code working perfectly. But from my customized form, it is not working.

Comment: Remove the tag 'dynamic-programming', it's no where related to dynamic programming!

Comment: Got the solution.                                                                                              A) Add reference to Microsoft.Dynamics.Retail.Pos.SystemCore DLL  (located in POS folder);

B) Use the following code you fetch Application object:

using Microsoft.Dynamics.Retail.Pos.SystemCore; //reference to standard DLL

var application = PosApplication.Instance as IApplication;